# Facebook Like Box works for only some users

Tags: facebook

My Facebook like box is not working for all users. Out of the 5 computers in my office it works perfectly on 3 of the computers and not on at all on the other 2, simply leaving a blank white space.

This code is used directly after the `<body>` tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YourAppIdHere";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And then the following code is used to display the Like Box:

```
<div id="facebook">
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Group1Nissan" data-width="460" data-height="400" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true" data-header="true"></div>
</div>
```

Why would it not display for some users, tested in the same browser and being logged in or out of facebook doesn't effect it.

Thanks in advance
Willem

Comment: So what is the problem tied to, specific computers/browsers, or users? If it is tied to specific machines, then how do you expect us to figure this out? (First step for you would be to disable all extensions that might be active in the browser.)

Comment: I have the problem only in Firefox on a single computer (Firefox on other computers works fine).

Comment: Does it show any console errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is only happened with (HTTPS) SSL certificate errors. I'm also faced this problem.

**Possible reasons:**

1. Please check time settings on your computer.
2. Check https://www.facebook.com/ link for SSL connection errors by browser (what problem
   makes)

Answer (score 1):

I have encounter this same issue multiple times. For your situation I would first check if the browser you're using is fully updated on all five computers to ensure consistency. Then once that is done, clear the cache and make sure no one is logged into Facebook before going to your site where the social plugin is located. If all five are broke it's a problem with that which is most of the time my issue when it shows up. If they all work your HTML5 was out of date on the computer where it didn't show before.

If you still have the same issue after that try using the iframe version of the like box.

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FFacebookDevelopers&amp;width&amp;height=590&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=true&amp;show_border=true&amp;" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:590px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Personally (having the same issue) I have the problem in Firefox on a single computer (even after clearing cache) but not in Chrome or any other browser. All other computers seem fine.

Answer (score 0):

Some times Facebook JS source link get problems.

You need to add http: in line 6 of the head script like this...

```
js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YourAppIdHere";
```

Comment: This should not be necessary and in fact will cause problems for users browsing your site over HTTPS

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code do you replace "YourAppIdHere" with your actual app id? 
That is found here: js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YourAppIdHere";

I assume that you probably changed that for posting here, but you should change that line to read:

js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YourAppIdHere";

Another potential issue is restrictions on your Facebook page such as age or location. If a person is not logged into Facebook and there are restrictions, FB will opt not to show the box because it can't determine a location or age.

Comment: This should not be necessary and in fact will cause problems for users browsing your site over HTTPS - the protocol-relative include of the JS SDK should be fine unless you're accessing the HTML file locally (e.g. the file:/// protocol)